# How can I produce half-way faded text?

Tags: c#, winforms, .net-4.0, drawing

The task is a simple concept, just not sure about a simple method to do what I'm asking.

---

### **Goal**

Have a textbox, label, custom User Control, or some other type of control show multiline text and fade it out half way down (as seen in image below).  I would like to have it be transparent (as seen in the image) and be editable of course.  I was thinking of something like a custom `UserControl : label` or something similar.  Maybe override the label's OnPaint and draw the form contents (everything behind the control) to emulate transparency.  Then draw the text but somehow maybe apply some type of gradient filter to it?  I honestly have no clue how I would do it but hoping someone else does.

Thanks!

[image]

Comment: It's better to put an image instead

Comment: Not an option...  It's text that changes dynamically.  But to be honest, technically I would be "putting up an image".  I would draw it at runtime.  :P

Comment: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/ded003e3-ab35-4c23-b645-af7f82df57f0/fade-the-text-in-a-label?forum=winforms a bit complicated, see if this helps?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I worked out a solution and it looks perfect, I'll need to spend more time on it later adding support for text align etc.  But for now I ended up coming up with this...

> **Note:** Create a new User Control and add this in the code area.  Also
>   keep in mind to make sure the designer of that new control uses the
>   same namespace "InfinityLabel".  And one last thing, don't forget to set your 
>   new label (InfinityLabel) to BackColor=Transparent.

```
using System.Drawing;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Drawing.Drawing2D;

namespace InfinityLabel
{
    public partial class InfinityLabel : Label
    {
        public InfinityLabel()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e)
        {
            Rectangle rect = new Rectangle(0, 0, Width, Height);
            LinearGradientBrush brush =
                new LinearGradientBrush(
                    rect, 
                    Color.FromArgb(255, ForeColor),
                    Color.FromArgb(60, ForeColor), 
                    90f);
            e.Graphics.DrawString(Text, Font, brush, rect);
        }
    }
}
```